# Fetch a column list when there are overlapping records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with Overlapping entries on `Profitcenter` and `FinancialAccount` created by multiple users.

I need to send email to users in `Submitteby` column for their overlapping entries (Say `PC1` and `CE1` have overlapping records, I should send email to both `abc` and `deg` and display both the records in the email).

How can this be done? Please help.

Below is the snapshot of the table.

```
ProfitCenterCode    FinancialAccountCode    FormName    SubmittedBy
PC1                  CE1                      SMSG       abc
PC1                  CE1                      SMSG       deg
PC2                  CE2                  MCB Dynamic    iol
PC2                  CE2                    N/A          ppp
PC2                  CE2                 MCB Dynamic     iol
PC2                  CE2                   MCB Dynamic   iol
PC2                  CE2                  MCB Dynamic    iol
PC2                  CE2                  MCB Dynamic    iol
```

Comment: Is there some code you have tried?

Comment: With that sample table data, what's the expected result?

Comment: Send email to abc, deg with below result set.                              ProfitCenterCode    FinancialAccountCode    FormName    SubmittedBy
PC1                        CE1                                     SMSG       abc
PC1                           CE1                                SMSG       deg

Comment: which database are you using

Answer (score 0):

Below query will produce a result like this

> ProfitCenterCode,FinancialAccountCode,FormName,SubmittedByList
>
> "PC1","CE1", "SMSG", "abc, deg"

```
   SELECT outer.ProfitCenterCode,outer.FinancialAccountCode,outer.FormName    
   (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ','+inner.SubmittedBy FROM <YOUR-TABLE> inner 
   WHERE inner.ProfitCenterCode = outer.ProfitCenterCode 
   and inner.FinancialAccountCode = outer.FinancialAccountCode
   and inner.FormName = outer.FormName 
   FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,"") AS SubmittedByList)
   FROM <YOUR-TABLE> outer
   GROUP BY outer.ProfitCenterCode,outer.FinancialAccountCode,outer.FormName
```

If you want to send as separate rows as you mentioned with this result set you must iterate thru each entry and query for below condition then send the result to SubmittedByList (split value by ',' if required)

```
 WHERE ProfitCenterCode = <entry-ProfitCenterCode>
       and FinancialAccountCode = <entry-FinancialAccountCode>
       and FormName = <entry-FormName>
```